# Spring LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap not returning value for keys with brackets?

Tags: java, spring, dictionary

I just wanted to confirm if this is a bug, or expected behavior. I was using a code segment that looks like this:

```
String sql = "select distinct wp.APP, max(wp.FUNCTIONALITY_DESCRIPTION) from test_table wp where wp.user = ?";
List<Map<String, Object>> rows = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql, new Object[] {user});
for (Map<String, Object> row : rows) {
    userSoftware.add(new Software((String) row.get("APP"), (String)row.get("MAX(WP.FUNCTIONALITY_DESCRIPTION)")));
}
```

I noticed that I was always getting the value of row.get("MAX(WP.FUNCTIONALITY_DESCRIPTION)") as null. I tried debugging the code, and even though I could see the value in the Map in the eclipse debugger, the get function call would always return null.

I then tried this code segment instead:

```
String sql = "select distinct wp.APP, max(wp.FUNCTIONALITY_DESCRIPTION) func_desc from test_table wp where wp.user = ?";
List<Map<String, Object>> rows = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql, new Object[] {user});
for (Map<String, Object> row : rows) {
    userSoftware.add(new Software((String) row.get("APP"), (String)row.get("func_desc")));
}
```

And I could get the value. Pardon any syntax errors in this code, I had to scrap of sensitive information, and might have broken something. But yes, the code did compile, and this example code is the best representation of my problem. Software here is a simple class with two String members, the appName and the description which are set by the constructor.
All I can see the difference between the two keys are the brackets. It is supposed to be case insensitive, but I did try with various combinations.

Comment: This problem is for SQL syntax, not Java nor Spring.

Comment: Pardon me Luiggi, but this seems to be an issue with a map having the key, and not returning me the value. My SQL is running fine in this case, and is returning values as expected.

Comment: If you select a `sum(someCol)` without setting an alias, the only way you can get the result is by using the ordinal number of the column (in this case, 2). When you use the second way you used `func_desc` as alias for your `max` function, so in the end you could get the result. Note that if you set the column name, you don't need an alias for it. And all this is SQL syntax (again, not Java, not Spring...)

Comment: Luiggi, I would agree with your comment if I was not seeing the value in the Eclipse debugger.I see the Map with the values in the debugger. Is that an artifact of the way the debugger works? If so, I will go ahead and close this question. Thanks!

Comment: So you say you can see the `Map` in your debugger with a key `MAX(WP.FUNCTIONALITY_DESCRIPTION)` (using the first case) or you can see the row with this key? By the way, the questions get closed if they're not good questions. In this case, the better would be to post an answer and accept it.

Comment: Now that I look at this question again after 2 years, I can see Luiggi's answer kinda makes sense. Although I still don't know why the map in the eclipse debugger had the key as MAX(WP.FUNCTIONALITY_DESCRIPTION) for the case without an alias. I guess the safer option is to always use an alias for such cases. Closing this question...